# power cable for My NVIDIA Quadro 4000

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to find a power cable for My NVIDIA Quadro 4000. My Dell server has an 8 pin connection on the Power Distribution Board and the GPU has a 6 pin slot. I can get both of these connections on different leads but can't find them as a combination in order to power my GPU.

What power supply provides both of these connections?

[image: Image of connection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word of caution: you've got a Dell.  Dell is known for using non-standard pinouts on their power supplies, so if possible, check the documentation before plugging anything in.

That said, I think the technical name for what you're looking for is an EPS-to-PCIe cable, such as [this Y-cable from Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812198035&ignorebbr=1&cm_re=pcie_power_cable-_-12-198-035-_-Product).  Yes, it's a Y-splitter rather than a straight-through cable, but the keying pattern matches what's in your picture.

Comment: Thank you so much for that information.  I have spent two weeks trawling the net hoping to find out what that was called. I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [LEPA MaxBron](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817494017) in my current machine which powers two nVidia boards. I've been very happy with it's performance.

It has a 6+2 set of connectors. This allows you to fit both the 6 and 8 pin power connectors. If you don't need the full 8 pins, the last two can be detached and don't need to be plugged in.

[image: 6+2 connector]

On top of this, it is fully modular, so you only need to plug in the power lines you need. This saves you trouble with wiring and improves airflow in the machine.

[image: Modular supply]

The 800W version of this power supply costs less than $100.

A few other features that are listed that may help your decision (from NewEgg):

- 80 PLUS BRONZE certified with over 88% efficiency
- 6+2P PCI-E connector supplied supporting extreme graphic cards
- Extended CPU connector cable to 23.6" (60cm) facilitates installation with bottom-mounted PSU chassis
- Anti3s Q-Brick design protects power supply from shock, static electricity, and slip